Ubuntu freezes at boot screen because of nvidia
Running on 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu with GeForce GT 750M.
I found an error whilst running optirun glxgear -info:
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "Nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

So I changed some configurations I didn't know, purged Bumblebee and Nvidia, installed them again, and did it again.
But now after installing nvidia-driver-418 Ubuntu will stop at the boot screen.
I tried installing nvidia-driver-390 but since my kernel is >6.5, it won't work.
Downgrading to 6.2.0-26-generic is impossible since it's deleted.
The boot screen (I am not sure if it's a boot screen) will have the Ubuntu logo with a loading logo underneath.

Please edit and add the Ubuntu version info you are using.

the reason why ubuntu freezes at boot screen when nvidia is installed is because of configuration files. libnvidia-compute-390:i386 and libnvidia-compute-470:i386 were not removed after running sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'. This causes nvidia to work with old configuration (i think the old confugaration makes nvidia think i still have bumblebee installed). I removed the libnvidia-compute packages now its working
